# Fiddling with a Fibonacci-Like Sequence

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Let $X\in\mathbb{Z}.$ 
Let $F_n$ be a sequence of positive integers given by

$$F_{i+1}=F_i+F_{i-1}$$

$$F_2=X*F_1+F_0$$

I am trying to find an upper bound or (sharp) inequality of $F_i$ in terms of $F_1$ and $F_0$.

If $F_{i+1}=F_i+F_{i-1}$ for all $i$, then substituting $F_i=q^i$ gives $F_i=(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^i$.

In our case,
$$F_j= (\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^j+(XF_1+F_0)-(F_1+F_0)= (\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^j+(X-1)F_1 \,\,(*)$$

Is the first equality in $(*)$ correct?

Comment: Note that $X$ can't be arbitrary, not if you want the $F_n$'s to be integers.

Comment: Taking $j=1$ in your equation yields $X=2-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2F_1}$, this is an irrational number. From, the first recurrence ,you get $X=\frac{F_2-F_0}{F_1}$, so this is an rational number. There is something wrong.

Comment: Substituting $i=1$ into the first of the two defining equations and comparing with the second gives $F_1 = 0$ or $X = 1$. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Peter, I imagine the first defining equation is meant to be applicable for $i\ge2$ only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general solution of $F_{i+1}=F_i+F_{i-1}$ is $F_j=A\phi^j+B\overline\phi\,^{j}$ where $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$ and $\overline\phi=(1-\sqrt5)/2$, and $A$ and $B$ are determined by the initial conditions. In your case the initial conditions are $F_1=F_1$ and $F_2=XF_1+F_0$. So you can substitute in $i=1$ and $i=2$ to get two linear equations for the two unknowns $A$ and $B$, and then you'll have your equation for $F_j$.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a formula in terms of Fibonacci numbers: Let $u_k$ denote the $k$th Fibonacci number, for $k=1,2,3,4$ the sequence $1,1,2,3,...$, and extend backwards to define $u_0=0$ and $u_{-1}=1$ (so the same recursion works on all the $u_k$). Then your sequence of polynomials is, using $b=F_0,\ a=F_1,$
$$F_k=au_kx+bu_{k-1},$$
which satisfies the recurrence (since the $u_k$ satisfy it), and gives $F_0$ and $xF_1$ for the first two values, thereafter matching the sequence generated by the recursion.
So bounds on the $F_i$ would involve knowing the initial $F_0,F_1$, as well as the range of values $x$ may take on, since if $x$ is not restricted there is no bound.

To fill this out and get a bound, use the fact that the Fibonacci number $u_n$ is alternately slightly above and below the value of $\phi^n/\sqrt{5}$ (above when $n$ is even), so that you may safely use the upper bound $B_n=(\phi^n/\sqrt{5}+1)$ for $u_n.$
Then if $0\le x \le d$ you have the bound
$$F_k \le aB_kd+bB_{k-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Any fibbonaccci series starting with (a,b) can be written as $a(1,0)+b(0,1)$. These two are the fibonacci series begining at $F(-1)$ and $F(0)$.

Counting these terms of the series start as $0$ and $1$, we have

$$T(n) = \phi^{n} (a /\phi +b) / \sqrt{5}$$

derived from adding two fibonacci convergences together.